# Данные на secondary реплике не сходятся с primary

Tags: sql-server

Есть база, некоторые таблички созданы как memory optimized, включил эту базу в always on как обычно, но данные расходятся - на secondary реплике в таблице данные на транзакцию назад. Вот тут говорится https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2014/09/24/potential-data-latency-with-alwayson-availability-groups-and-memory-optimized-tables/ что возможны несколько секунд задержки, но прошло гораздо больше, а данные расходятся. В чем проблема? Как добиться консистентности данных?

Comment: Вы видимо как-то не очень внимательно прочли информацию по приведённой вами ссылке. Человек пишет как раз, что даже после нескольких секунд ожидания данные не появлялись на secondary, и как он это решил, и даёт ссылку на документацию, где это объясняется, и даётся рекомендованный способ решения _"run a few DML transactions on a dummy durable memory-optimized table on the primary replica"_. В версии 2016 это момент похоже исправили.